# Connecting Truffle, Remix and Ganache

Tags: contract-development, truffle, remix, ganache

I'm learning Solidity and all that and managed to make these three (Ganache, Truffle and Remix) work, no big problems so far.

But now I'm messing with basic smart contracts and noticed this:

1. If I deploy/migrate via truffle, I get my smart contract listed in Ganache in the "Contracts" tab. This is very useful obviously to see the state of the contract etc.
2. I connected to the same Ganache network from Remix via the Web3 Provider, and can deploy contracts from Remix (since Remix has a code editor it seems to me this is a better choice than using truffle alone for actual development)
3. If I deploy contracts from inside Remix, they don't show in the "Contracts" tab in Ganache. In fact I can deploy a contract several times (I assume since no migration step here) and I get a new contract address each time.

I think I'm missing some final step where I can link all these three together?

So basically using Remix as code editor but using truffle for deployment and migration and so Ganache shows all the info? I have not see settings for this inside Remix in the deployment section. Maybe there is a plugin for Truffle?

Thank you